# Creating an Alternate Install CD with pre installed users

Tags: live-cd, users, customization, livedvd, customizer

I want to create my own customized Ubuntu derivative and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd) already gave me a very good start. My requirements are quite specific I want to roll out a CD with

- Set of users who are supposed to run them (root, admin, guest) pre-installed
- With their passwords already set
- Installation not asking for creating users on booting or during OS installation
- Autologin to guest user

Is this even possible?

Thanks to the community in advance :)

Comment: As far as i know, guest users are created automatically upon login. So, last step may not be possible. yes a regular user without admin power will be

Comment: ok, I can work withough having autologin, what about other two? What about installing without having installation asking for users to create, not even root user.

Comment: Looking around I can across [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization). I think preseeding might be an answer to this. Will post an answer once I am able to build it successfully.